# How to query objects 10 minutes in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got a Reminder object that serves as a normalized object for different other objects with starts_at attributes like Meeting, Event.

I need to create a rake task to look for and run reminders for these objects. I need to find Reminder objects that starts in ten minutes from now but the code I try does not do the job.

*My code I try is:*

```
Reminder.where('reminds_at = ?', 10.minutes.from_now)
```

The Reminder object got an attribute (datetime) that is called reminds_at. Is there also a way to make sure it uses the users timezone?

Comment: This code will work only if the reminds_at does not contain seconds.  Might try...```Reminder.where('reminds_at >= ? AND reminds_at < ?  ', 10.minutes.from_now, 11.minutes_from_now)```.

Comment: Looks to work! Any idea how to take timezones into account?

Comment: that entirely depends on how you created the data

Comment: With no timezones in mind. In server UTC format (rails default)

Comment: Then you need decide how to relate the dates you have to what you need